# epplus read signature c#

Tags: c#, excel, digital-signature, epplus

I am trying to read  a digital signature in the excel file 
I need to read Signature Text(The person's name)  and Signature Title(His designation/Title under signature line)  .I can do it via Interop.Excel and openOffice.xml , but i still need to do the same thing via EPPlus. Is it possible to do the same thing via EPPlus. Please find the code for Interop.Excel

```
Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(strFile)

SignatureSet allSignatures = excelWorkbook.Signatures;

foreach (Signature digitalSign in allSignatures)
{                          
  signedTitle = digitalSign.Setup.SuggestedSignerLine2;
  signedName = digitalSign.Details.SignatureText;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need:

```
using (var xls = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo))
{
    var name = xls.Workbook.Properties.Author;
    var title = xls.Workbook.Properties.Title;
}
```

I don't see any other signatures (other than Zip file-related) in EPPlus:

https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/search?q=signature&unscoped_q=signature